# Google Map and Navigation with KML overlay

Tags: android, google-maps, kml, google-fusion-tables

Looking for some advice and guidance here. I volunteer at a fire dept., we have android based tablets on our trucks that we use for navigation. They work great for this. We are able to receive our dispatch data automatically and have it start navigation before even leaving our station.

One feature we would like to add is having Fire Hydrants display as an Overlay on Google Maps and possibly Navigation.

We have a KML file with all of the Hydrants (over 6,000) however, if we try to import into Google Maps (from desktop) under "my places" we are limited to approx. 1,000 points and unable to import all 6,000. They will display on the android Google Maps, however not in Navigation and unable to store as offline.

We have been able to import all of the hydrants into a Google Fusion successfully. They are located at https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1tXSDF4N4b_woBggNMYHSVpZjC_z5w1T-txcR5bA

The KML file we are working with is at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/31421184/123.kml

1. Is there a way to have these from Google Fusion, display on Google Map on an Android device? Any Fusion to Maps integration for Android?
2. If not able to have Google Fusion integrate with Google Maps, is there a way to have Google Maps on Android display or import the KML file? With all of our 6,000 points?
3. Is there a way to have Google Map store Maps Offline with the Overlays we need?
4. If Google Maps is unable to provide us our solution, is there one that can be recommended? Have looked at Locus and OruxMaps and the interface is not as simple as what we need. Google is preferred by far.

Comment: I can't answer the questions fully and completely, but I can tell you that it might be helpful to generate tiles with dots for each of the hydrant locations, and overlay the tiles.  (They don't need to be as fully-featured as Markers, I presume?  You won't ever want to display an InfoWindow for a hydrant, right?)

Comment: Like this: http://maps.webfoot.com/mapeteria2/dots.php?points=dotAttributes&name=hydrants&year=2013&colour=ff0000&size=1&x=284&y=397&zoom=10

Comment: Whoops!  The Android maps API doesn't have the ability to overlay tiles.  Sorry.

Comment: Something you could do is use make a web page (using Google Maps) which had the tile overlays.  I am not sure how well offline mode would work there, and the Terms of Use for web pages might preclude storing their maps.  If you need a less restrictive license, you could use leaflet and/or Open Street Map tiles.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Still looking for a solution.

Comment: The Android Maps API v2 has this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/tileoverlay